# Efficient Searching in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to search a keyword in pandas dataframe. Currently I am using isin() method to search the entire dataframe, it is working correctly but it is taking a lot of time when dealing with big dataset exceeding 1 Gb.

The problem I am addressing is :

Suppose I have a dataset df :

```
Player_Name      Country       Type_of_sports

Messi            Argentina     Football
Ronaldo          Portugal      Football
Kohli            India         Cricket
Federer          Switzerland   Tennis
```

Column name - Player_Name, Country,Type_of_sports

So if a user enters a query for example:

```
query = 'Which country is Messi from ?'
```

So my keyword in this query will be `Messi`.

So now I need to search for `Messi` in my entire dataframe.

So is there any efficient method to search and find such data values in data-frame without using for loop or isin() method??

Note - It is not always the case that the query will always contain the exact column name.

For example - 
new_query- 'Name of players playing `football` '.

Now here I need to search for keyword `Football` in the entire data-frame.
Is there any method to search for `Football` without using for loop or isin() function.

Thank you

Comment: you mean `df[df.Player_Name.isin(query.split())]` ?? how dynamic can the query be

Comment: sorry for not defining the types of queries properly. I have edited my question. Please find the changes and give any suggestions for my problem. thanks @anky_91

Answer (score 0):

To efficiently answer that query, you can use the following:

```
df.loc[df.Player_Name == 'Messi', 'Country']
```

```
'Argentina'
```

If a given player name does not exist in that column, there will be no matches, and an empty series will be returned.

Comment: thank you for answering the query. I have made some changes in my post. I want to search for 'Messi' not knowing whether Argentina belongs to country column. So I have to seach for Argentina in my entire data frame to find that it belongs to country column. Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't know of a way to search the entire data frame for a value more efficiently that using ``df.isin()``. If you are working with large data sets, you will experience some slowdowns. Pandas should be able to handle 1 GB, but above 100 GB you may be better off using other tools such as Spark/Hadoop.